# c++ , pthread and static callbacks. "this" returns a pointer to the base class inctead of the derived one

Tags: c++, multithreading, class, this, derived-class

I am using as basis [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-169477.html) cpp thread class. This I use as a base class for threads. Note that in my case Thread::main() is  a virtual function (unlike in the link). So I basically use:

```
class Thread {
public:
    virtual void main()
    {
        cout << "This should not be run once derived and redefined." << endl;
    }

    void run()
    {
        pthread_create(&thread, 0, &callback, this);
    }

    pthread_t thread;
}; // class Thread


void* callback(void* obj)
{
    static_cast<Thread*>(obj)->main();
    return(0);
} // callback
```

Then I create a derived class and re-define the `myThreadedClass::main()` member to actually do something meaningful.

Finally, I instantiate the myThreadedClass object from other classes or my main function call as follows:

```
main(int argc, char** argv){
    myThreadedClass thr;
    thr.run();

    //do other stuff
}
```

This works fine; The callback function gets a pointer to the derived class instantiation, so the `myThreadedClass::main()` gets executed.

However, I now try to create a different derived class `class otherThreadClass : public Thread`. Again I re-define my `otherThreadClass::main()` , but now I have a member function in the derived class which (unlike before) calls Thread::run().

```
class otherThreadClass : public Thread{
public:
    writeToDiskAsync(string& str){
       prepareString(str);

       //spawn a thread to carry the write without blocking execution
       run();
    }
};
```

in this case from my main function I do

```
main(int argc, char** argv){
    otherThreadClass thr;
    thr.writeToDiskAsync(aString);

    //do other stuff
}
```

The problem in this case is that the callback function gets a pointer to the Thread class and the Thread::main() ends up being executed instead of the otherThreadClass::main().

I tried passing a pointer to the instantiated myThreadedClass object during instantiation (using initialisation lists and an altered call to Thread::run(void* instance)) as follows

```
//in main function
otherThreadClass thr(&thr);

//in class
otherThreadClass::otherThreadClass(otherThreadClass* ptr):instancePtr(ptr)
{}

otherThreadClass::writeToDiskAsync(string& str)
{
    //do stuff
    run(instancePtr);
}

//and finally

Thread::run(void* parentObj)
{
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, &callback, parentObj);
}
```

but it does not work. And I think this is probably not a nice way to do it anyway. So what can I do to let the callback function get apointer to the derived class instance instead of the base class ?

thank you

Comment: Make the functions you intend to override **virtual**. C++ doesn't do dynamic binding by default.

Comment: @StoryTeller sorry, they are virtual in the base class. I edited the question.

Comment: Okay, than. Do you have a join operation someplace towards the end of main?

Comment: Your failure to actually post the code you are working on, and then editing in changes, removes any faith I have that the code above will reproduce your problem.  Can you produce an actual https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and test it yourself to confirm it produces the effect you are discussing?  Then post that MCVE?

Comment: Well the only thing I see in your snippets is that `otherThreadClass` doesn't override `main()`, so naturally `Thread::main` is called. You can catch such errors at compile time by making `main` pure virtual.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok I see this is confusing. I will return with a MCVE example as Yakk suggested.

Comment: I bet `otherThreadClass::main()` signature does not match parent. There are enough ways to prevent such errors in C++ - pure virtual, override, and use `std::thread` instead of `pthread`

Comment: @Slava nope this is not it.

Comment: @nass then just make `Thread::main()` pure virtual and see what compiler will tell you. It should be pure virtual anyway.

Comment: @Slava please see this question for a clear case of what is going on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440316/c-pthread-and-static-callbacks-this-returns-a-pointer-to-the-base-class-i?noredirect=1#comment56621947_34440316

Comment: @StoryTeller ok Here is the MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440316/c-pthread-and-static-callbacks-this-returns-a-pointer-to-the-base-class-i?noredirect=1#comment56621947_34440316

Comment: @Yakk this may be easier to follow through and test http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440316/c-pthread-and-static-callbacks-this-returns-a-pointer-to-the-base-class-i?noredirect=1#comment56621947_34440316

Answer (score 0):

If you will try to call a function using base class ptr , everytime base class version gets called as long as function is not virtual .
so simpler solution to your problem would be to make main virtual as below :

```
  #include <iostream>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h?
using namespace std;
void* callback(void* obj);
class Thread {
public:
  virtual  int main()
    {
        cout << "Hi there Base class" << endl;
        return(0);
    }

    void run()
    {
        pthread_create(&thread, 0, &callback, this);
    }

    pthread_t thread;
};

class otherThreadClass : public Thread{
public:
virtual  int main()
    {
        cout << "Hi there other class" << endl;
        return(0);
    }


   void writeToDiskAsync(string str){


       //spawn a thread to carry the write without blocking execution
       run();
    }
};

class Thread;
void* callback(void* obj)
{
    static_cast<Thread*>(obj)->main();
    return(0);
} // callback


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    otherThreadClass thr;
    thr.writeToDiskAsync(string("aS"));
sleep(10);//it is neccessary as main thread can exit before .
    return 0;
}
output : Hi there other class
```

Whereas if main is not virtual , it will always call base class version of main as you are calling through a base class ptr (static binding will happen )

Comment: main is virtual. I wish that would have been the solution :)

Comment: @ nass : did you even try to run the program as i got desired output ?In my program it will call the main function of other class .check it again !

Comment: @nass: To sum up , if main is virtual ..derived class version will be called(if object is of dervied type ) .If main is not virtual , always base class version will get called .If main is virtual in your code then there is no way by which base class version of "main" would be called using derived object .double check it .If you are still facing problem ,paste your code here.

Comment: hi there, which compiler are you using , `g++`? Thank you for wanting to help. Here is a clear example of what is going on. Perhaps you can pin point the problem in this one?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34440316/c-pthread-and-static-callbacks-this-returns-a-pointer-to-the-base-class-i?noredirect=1#comment56621947_34440316

Comment: @nass : yes nass , I am using g++ and code is working fine on g++ and i believe it should work fine on other compilers too :) .Ok let me check the link

Comment: @nass:just edited the complete working example .hope it will help :)

Comment: @SACHINGOYAL, `sleep` is no alternative at all to a proper thread join operation. This is unsafe still.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Agree .The idea was to keep main thread on wait for some time such that other thread can do its work ."pthread_join" is anyway a far better option .

Comment: I'm glad you concur, but your example code is still an anti-pattern. It makes the answer bad for any novice that reads it.