# c++ , pthread and static callbacks. "this" returns a pointer to the base class inctead of the derived one (part 2)

Tags: c++, callback, pthreads, this, derived-class

this thread was started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34438946/c-pthread-and-static-callbacks-this-returns-a-pointer-to-the-base-class-i) but due to lack of an altogether good example (and in order to avoid delete all that question) it is re-written here.

So, in the following example, the `void cppthread::ThreadedFunc()` gets spawned to execute as a separate thread . Instead I would prefer `void ThreadedWrite::ThreadedFunc()` to be executed. How can I do that? (some more details follow after the code)

cppthread.hpp

```
#ifndef CPPTHREAD_HPP
#define CPPTHREAD_HPP

#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;

class cppthread
{
    public:
        cppthread();
        virtual ~cppthread();

        virtual void threadedFunc();
        ///parentObj (ie "this" pte from caller") is 
        ///necessary in order to execute the correct
        ///threadedFunc() even when the derived class
        ///wants to spawn a thread.
        int spawn(void *parentObj = NULL);
        void terminate();

    protected:
        pthread_mutex_t mtx;
        bool exitThread;

    private:
        /* add your private declarations */
        int join();

        pthread_t threadId;
};

#endif /* CPPTHREAD_HPP */
```

cppthread.cpp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "cppthread.hpp"

void* threadCallback(void* obj);

cppthread::cppthread()
{
    exitThread = false;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, NULL);

}


cppthread::~cppthread()
{
    if (!exitThread)
        terminate();
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mtx);
}

void cppthread::threadedFunc()
{
    while ( !exitThread )
    {
        printf("Hello from cppthread::threadfunc. This should not be run once derived and redefined.\n");
    }
    if (exitThread)
    {
        printf("graceful exit from cppthread::threadfunc. This should not be run once derived and redefined.\n");
    }
    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

int cppthread::spawn(void* parentObj)
{
    int ret;
    printf("parentObj = %p\n", parentObj);
    if (parentObj == NULL)
    {
        ret = pthread_create(&threadId, 0, &threadCallback, this);
        printf("cppthread_create with \"this\" \n");
    }
    else
    {
        ret = pthread_create(&threadId, 0, &threadCallback, parentObj);
        printf("cppthread_create with parentObj\n");
    }

    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("cppthread_create error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        //printf("cppthread::threadID= %lu\n",threadId);
    }
    return ret;
}

void cppthread::terminate()
{
    exitThread = true;
    join();
}

int cppthread::join()
{
    int status , ret;
    //printf("cppthread::join_threadID= %lu\n",threadId);
    ret = pthread_join(threadId,(void**)&status);
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("cppthread_join error: ");
        switch (ret)
        {
            case EDEADLK: printf("deadlock\n"); break;
            case EINVAL: printf("thread not joinable\n"); break;
            case ESRCH: printf("threadID not found\n"); break;
            default : printf("unknown error\n"); break;
        }
    }
    return status;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
void* threadCallback(void* obj)
{
    static_cast<cppthread*>(obj)->threadedFunc();
    return(0);
} // callback
```

threadedwrite.hpp

```
#ifndef THREADEDWRITE_HPP
#define THREADEDWRITE_HPP

#include "cppthread.hpp"

using namespace std;

class ThreadedWrite : public cppthread
{
    public:
        ThreadedWrite(ThreadedWrite* mySelf);
        virtual ~ThreadedWrite();

        void threadedFunc();
        void rrdupdate_thread();

        ///inherited significant members: from cppthread
        ///   int spawn();
        ///   void terminate();
        ///protected
        ///   pthread_mutex_t mtx;
        ///   bool exitThread;

    private:
        ThreadedWrite* instancePtr;
};

#endif /* THREADEDWRITE_HPP */
```

threadedwrite.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "threadedwrite.hpp"


ThreadedWrite::ThreadedWrite(ThreadedWrite* mySelf):instancePtr(mySelf)
{
    cout << "instancePtr = " << instancePtr << endl;
}

ThreadedWrite::~ThreadedWrite()
{

}

void ThreadedWrite::threadedFunc()
{
    if ( !exitThread )
    {
        cout << "this is the ThreadedWrite::threadedFunc() running!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ThreadedWrite::threadedFunc must exist now" << endl;
    }

    pthread_exit((void*)0);
}

void ThreadedWrite::rrdupdate_thread()
{
    cout << "about to spawn" << endl;
    spawn(instancePtr);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

#include "threadedwrite.hpp"

using namespace std;

//-------main body------------------------------------------------------
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ThreadedWrite  thrrdupd(&thrrdupd);
    cout << "hello from main 1 " << &thrrdupd << endl;
    thrrdupd.rrdupdate_thread();
    cout << "hello from main 2 " << &thrrdupd << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above produces the output (for me):

```
instancePtr = 0x7fff39d17860
hello from main 1 0x7fff39d17860
about to spawn
parentObj = 0x7fff39d17860
cppthread_create with parentObj
hello from main 2 0x7fff39d17860
graceful exit from cppthread::threadfunc. This should not be run once derived and redefined.
```

So executing the above `cppthread::spawn()` call from within the derived class "ThreadedWrite" , actually provides a "this" pointer to `callback()` function that points to `cppthread::ThreadedFunc()`, instead of `ThreadedWrite::ThreadedFunc()`.

You can also see that I tried (through the "instancePtr" infrastructure) to pass a pointer to the instance of "ThreadedWrite" back to the callback function. But this failed too.

Also, preferably I would like to keep cppthread class as generic as possible in order to be able to use it in may cases.

Mind you, if I remove "spawn(instancePtr)" from threadedwrite.cpp , and call the spawn from main.cpp like this

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        ThreadedWrite  thrrdupd(&thrrdupd);
        cout << "hello from main 1 " << &thrrdupd << endl;
        thrrdupd.rrdupdate_thread();
        thrrdupd.spawn();
        cout << "hello from main 2 " << &thrrdupd << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

the output that I get Is the expected (and wanted) one and it looks like this:

```
instancePtr = 0x7ffd24b04ed0
hello from main 1 0x7ffd24b04ed0
about to spawn
parentObj = (nil)
cppthread_create with "this" 
hello from main 2 0x7ffd24b04ed0
this is the ThreadedWrite::threadedFunc() running!
```

Comment: Why are you storing `instancePtr` rather than just using `this`?

Comment: @AlanStokes when the "this" pointer in the callback() function points to the base and not the derived object. So I was trying to verify if what I want gets passed on correctly. I agree it is now redundant code .

Comment: So no join operation in main after all

Comment: Btw why you do not use `std::thread` and all that nonsense with pthread?

Comment: In the future, you can just edit your original question, especially if you are just fixing your code sample and not *changing* the question and there are no valid answers to your original question.

Comment: @Slava well because I come from a C background , and I also try to avoid using C++11 for this project, so I never really tried them.

Comment: @Slava, `pthread` is hardly nonsense. Neither as learning exercise or as the popular backend of `std::thread`

Comment: @StoryTeller I really though that a derived class acted as a monolithic class (base + derived). I did not know the derived can die while the base still lives on... This is something new to learn today.

Comment: @StoryTeller I did not say that `pthread` is nonsense. But wrapping C library in C++ when it has native library now is. Especially on Windows where pthread is wrapper by itself.

Comment: @Slava I will take a look into `std::threads` as well. seems I was stuck with an old thing I read somewhere some time ago. I cannot find the link now, but more or less it said that if you want good threads either do `pthreads` or go for `boost::threads`. or something like that. it seems it is not the case anylonger.

Comment: @nass `boost::thread` is adopted by standard and became `std::thread`, usage is pretty much the same. It is very easy to switch from one to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wait for the thread to terminate before you return from `main`, because that destroys your object.

Otherwise you have a race condition:

1. The thread is started.
2. `thrrdupd` starts to be destoyed as you leave `main`.
3. `~ThreadedWrite` runs; at this point the object is no longer a `ThreadedWrite` but a `cppthread`.
4. `~cppthread` runs and waits for the thread.
5. The thread calls the callback and because the object now has dynamic type `cppthread`, `cppthread::threadedFunc` is called.

It is possible that 5. might happen before 3., in which case you will get the expected output.

If you make sure you wait for the thread to finish at step 3. then it will work fine. Perhaps you could call `terminate` inside `~ThreadedWrite`?

Comment: I really thought that a derived class acted as unified block class (base + derived). I did not know the derived can die while the base still lives on... I thought the `~ThreadWrite()`, also calls `~cppthread()`.  This is something new to learn today.

Comment: @nass you do not understand the issue. Both destructors are called indeed, but that does not happen instantly, there is race condition - while `~ThreadWrite()` is working you call virtual function.

Comment: Thanks Alan for this great explanation .

Comment: @nass: i missed to tell you on previous link that i kept the main thread on sleep because of the same , I got the expected output .